# Get real exe location path

Tags: powershell, working-directory

I am trying to execute 2 exe (`File1.exe` and `File2.exe`) via 
 another script converted to exe (`Run.exe`) .. it works fine when I use the lines in the `Run.exe` script:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "$(Get-Location)\Folder1\File1.exe"
Start-Process -FilePath "$(Get-Location)\Folder2\File2.exe"
```

The problem is that `File1.exe` and `File2.exe` get the location of the launcher (which is `Run.exe`) instead of their own:

My schema is:

```
Desktop\run.exe
Desktop\folder1\file1.exe
Desktop\folder2\file2.exe
```

script in `File1.exe` and `file2.exe` is:

```
write-host "$(Get-Location)"
```

So this must print `C:\Users\Sensei\Desktop\folder1` and `C:\Users\Sensei\Desktop\folder2` in the console windows of `file1.exe` and `file2.exe` when I run the launcher (`Run.exe`), but what I get is the launcher path, which is `C:\Users\Sensei\Desktop`

Comment: Your question is interesting; I suspect it was down-voted  due to lack of proper [formatting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777), which made it hard to understand. Also, while the impulse to include them is commendable, it's ultimately better to avoid salutations, good wishes, ... - in the long run, future readers appreciate a focus on just the issue at hand; see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260791/45375

Comment: I see what you mean, thank you for the notice x) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is here :

```
$FullPathToEXE = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName

$DirectoryContainingEXE = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($FullPathToEXE)
```

Comment: Nice; a slightly shorter solution that may also work is `Split-Path ([Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs()[0])`. It's worth mentioning what script-to-exe converter you're using.

Comment: I am using Win-PS2EXE, I will mentionne it next time, thanks x)